# Uniform convergence of the given series in the domain $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, sequence-of-function

Check whether the following series of function is uniformly convergent in $\Bbb R$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}.$$
If the ddomain is any bounded interval then by Weierstrass M-test the series converges uniformly. But I am unable to check the uniform convergence when the domain is $\Bbb R$.

How to check ? Any hint. please?